# How to update Datagridview in my 1st User control after i register into the 2nd User Control

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Two user control.
The First user control have a Datagridview.
The Second User control is a Registration.
How the datagridview on the First user control will refresh/update after i register on the Second user control.

- Note: I use Two User control. Not Form

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your registration call an event (buttonOnClick...)
Then load your second Panel by making data provider re-read its source:

```
var dataprovider = (System.Windows.Data.XmlDataProvider) (
  ((UserControl1) (elementHost1.Child)).Resources ["rssData"]
);
dataprovider.Refresh ();
```

Comment: after i write the System.Windows. the next word is only a .form there's no .Data